# Adding a filament sensor

Tags: anet-a6

I have the Anet A6 and I was wondering if it is possible to add a filament run-out sensor. I would feel better having something to stop the filament before it runs through and I have to take apart the extruder.

Comment: what firmware do you have on your a6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With marlin firmware:

source here: [filiament sensor config](http://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html#filament-runout-sensor)

```
//#define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR
#if ENABLED(FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SENSOR)
  #define FIL_RUNOUT_INVERTING false // set to true to invert the logic of the sensor.
  #define ENDSTOPPULLUP_FIL_RUNOUT // Uncomment to use internal pullup for filament runout pins if the sensor is defined.
  #define FILAMENT_RUNOUT_SCRIPT "M600"
#endif
```

> With this feature, a mechanical or opto endstop switch is used to
>   check for the presence of filament in the feeder (usually the switch
>   is closed when filament is present). If the filament runs out, Marlin
>   will run the specified GCode script (by default “M600”). RAMPS-based
>   boards use SERVO3_PIN. For other boards you may need to define
>   FIL_RUNOUT_PIN.

and this is a nice piece of hardware: [run out sensor](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2147179)

Comment: Gorgeous!  i was going to suggest the disastrous panic-stop by having the runout switch kill main power.  That pretty much ruins the print in progress.  I"m off to see if my driver board has those pins available.

Comment: Great! Now I will design the sensor.